# Ionic2 sqlitePlugin is not defined

Tags: ionic2

How to evade this error: VM18193:27 Unable to open database ReferenceError: sqlitePlugin is not defined(…)

```
    setTimeout(function() {
      let db = new SQLite();
      db.openDatabase({
        name: "data.db",
        location: "default"
      }).then(() => {
        db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT)", {}).then((data) => {
          console.log("TABLE CREATED: ", data);

        }, (error) => {
          console.error("Unable to execute sql", error);
        })
      }, (error) => {
        console.error("Unable to open database", error);
      });
    }, 2000);
```

How can i execute some query?

```js
if(SqlSettingsService.openDb){
      this.db = SqlSettingsService.getDB();
      this.db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT", {}).then
```

instead i get error.
console:

```
SqlSettingsService() starts
VM21750:27 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'executeSql' of null ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'executeSql' of null(…) TypeError: Cannot read property 'executeSql' of null
```

Comment: The error happens in a browser or on a real device?

Comment: @nyluje, in a browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin sqlLite does not work in a browser, you can use Websql for the browser instead (with compatible browsers, including Chrome and Opera as far as I know).

Transactions written for Websql are compatible with transactions written for SQLite.

Here is a service I have done to manage the Connection to the DB and make it work regardless if the program runs in a browser or a on real device:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SQLite } from 'ionic-native';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class SqlSettingsService {

    private db: any = null;
    private isOpened: boolean = false;


    constructor() { 
        console.log('SqlSettingsService() starts');
    }

    public getDB(){
        return this.db;
    }

    public openDb = (platform:Platform,winSer:any):Promise<any> => {
        console.log('SqlSettingsService() opend DB starts');
        let p:Promise<any>;
        if(!this.isOpened){
            this.isOpened = true;

            if(platform.is('core')){
                this.db = winSer.window.openDatabase("ionic2BrowserDev","1.0","",5*1024*1024);
                p = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){resolve('websql success')});
            } else {
                this.db = new SQLite();
                p = this.db.openDatabase({
                    name: 'data.db',
                    location: 'default' // the location field is required
                }).then(
                    ()=>{console.log("SqlSettingsService open db successful")},
                    (err)=>{console.error(err)}
                );
            }

        } else {
             p = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
                resolve('db already opened');
             });
        }
        return p;

    }

    public closeDb = () => {
        this.isOpened = false;
        return this.db.close();
    }


}
```

winSer is another service to access the window Object that I use in my app.component.ts when I call openDB() on SqlSettingsService. It's just this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class WindowService {
  public window = window;
}
```

To execute query:

```
    [SqlSettingsService-instance].openDb();
[SqlSettingsSevice-instance].getDB().transaction(
            function(tx){
                tx.executeSql([your sql],[bracket values you want to pass],success,error);
                function success(tx,rs){
                     console.log("success exec sql: ")
                     console.info(rs);

                }
                function error(tx,error){
                     console.log('execSqlCustom error ' + error.message + " for tx " + tx);

                }
            });
```

Comment: I added some details about executing query. Ultimately I'd advise to use Promise or Observables to manage the async SQL results.

Comment: you ve forgotten the success and error function in your sqlExecute

Comment: have a look to that also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347687/ionic-2-sqlite-manage-callback-with-promise

Comment: What is winSer? winSer.window.openDatabase

Comment: winSer is `window` object service (it is detailed in my answer). You need to access the `window` object of the browser to use websql commands.