# SQLite executeSql undefined even though platform is ready

Tags: sqlite, angular, ionic2

After hours of error researching I couldn't find out why I get over and over the same warning. The described behaviour occures, when I interact too fast with the app. My guess would be that the problem lies that this.db (SQLite instance) is in a service and as the service is a singleton it might be another one is already accessing it which leads in an undefined this.db instance.

[image: Console log]

The platform is an instance of Platform class which is part of cordova. and this is the code in typescript:

```
read(id: number): Promise<[DBObject|undefined, DBAttributes|undefined]|undefined> {
    return this.platform.ready()
        .then(() => this.db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM OBJECTS WHERE id = ?', [id]))
        .then(obj => {
            return this.db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM ATTRIBUTES WHERE objects_id = ?', [id])
                .then(attr => {
                    let object = (obj) ? obj.rows.item(0) : undefined;
                    let attributes = (attr) ? attr.rows.item(0) : undefined;
                    return [object, attributes];
                });
        })
        .catch(err => this.error.handleDBError(err));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also use a service (provider to use angular vocabulary) but only to get the connection to the DB. For all other operations (the SQL queries) I made a self standing class (not a component, a directive or a provider):

```
    import {DBCon} from [service db];

    export class QuerySet{...}
```

In the constructor of that class, I pass the connection to the DB. I never had a problem as the one you describe so far.

Comment: What are the benefits of your implementations? Why did you decide to do it like this?

Comment: It made sense to me to have a class to manage all the standard queries, and it seemed good to keep the connection to the db separated from that class. Now having a second look at your code, I think that maybe it misses a 'return' in front of the first 'this.db.executeSql' and also you could maybe have a look to that previous answer I had given: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653493/ionic2-sqliteplugin-is-not-defined/40656960#40656960