# How to process the return from sqlite Select statement in ionic 2?

Tags: android-sqlite, ionic2

I'm working on a Ionic 2 (`2.0.0-rc.2`) app with a sqlite storage and i've ran into some problems, hence i'm seeking for help here.

When starting the app for the first time i'm creating the database(tables) insert a few values. So far everything goes alright. However when I try to retrieve data and read it from the database i'm getting an error.

**The class were i'm talking about:**

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {StatusBar, Splashscreen, SQLite} from 'ionic-native';
import {HomePage} from '../pages/home/home';


@Component({
    template: `<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>`
})
export class MyApp {
    users = [];
    rootPage = HomePage;

    constructor(platform: Platform) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
            let db = new SQLite();
            console.log("open database app.compontent")
            db.openDatabase({
                name: "data.db",
                location: "default"
            }).then(() => {
                db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (iduser INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT, castleType TEXT, castleHealth INTEGER); ", {}).then((data) => {
                    console.log("USER TABLE CREATED: ", data);
                }, (error) => {
                    console.error("USER Unable to execute sql", error);
                });
                db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS melding (idmelding INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, meldingType TEXT, meldingTitel TEXT, meldingOmschrijving TEXT, ruimte INTEGER, user_iduser INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (user_iduser) REFERENCES user(iduser)); ", {}).then((data) => {
                    console.log("MELDING TABLE CREATED: ", data);
                }, (error) => {
                    console.error("MELDING Unable to execute sql", error);
                });
                db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kasteelOnderdelen (idkasteelOnderdelen INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, onderdeelNaam TEXT, onderdeelShort TEXT, onderdeelHealth TEXT); ", {}).then((data) => {
                    console.log("KASTEELONDERDELEN TABLE CREATED: ", data);
                }, (error) => {
                    console.error("KASTEELONDERDELEN Unable to execute sql", error);
                });
                db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_has_kasteelOnderdelen (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, user_iduser INTEGER, kasteelOnderdelen_idkasteelOnderdelen INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (user_iduser) REFERENCES user(iduser), FOREIGN KEY (kasteelOnderdelen_idkasteelOnderdelen) REFERENCES kasteelOnderdelen(idkasteelOnderdelen));", {}).then((data) => {
                    console.log("USER_HAS_KASTEELONDERDELEN TABLES CREATED: ", data);
                }, (error) => {
                    console.error("USER_HAS_KASTEELONDERDELEN Unable to execute sql", error);
                });
                console.log('Creating database complete!');
                db.executeSql("INSERT INTO user (firstname, lastname, castletype, castleHealth) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", ['Jan', 'Klaassen', 'mannelijk', '10']).then((data) => {

                    console.log("Inserted row 1: ", data);
                }, (error) => {
                    console.error("Unable to insert row 1: ", error);
                });
                db.executeSql("INSERT INTO user (firstname, lastname, castletype, castleHealth) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", ['Klaas', 'Janssen', 'mannelijk', '5']).then((data) => {

                    console.log("Inserted row 2: ", data);
                }, (error) => {
                    console.error("Unable to insert row 2: ", error);
                });
                db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM user', []).then((resultSet) => {
                    if(resultSet.res.rows.length > 0) {
                        this.users = [];
                        for(let i = 0; i < resultSet.res.rows.length; i++) {
                            this.users.push({
                                "iduser": resultSet.res.rows.item(i).iduser,
                                "firstname": resultSet.res.rows.item(i).firstname,
                                "lastname": resultSet.res.rows.item(i).lastname,
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }, (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });

            }, (error) => {

                console.error("Unable to open database", error);
            });
            Splashscreen.hide();
        });
    }
}
```

**error (when I run it on a device (Nexus 5):**

```
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 12 : Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined
                                                                                         at s (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:8568)
                                                                                         at file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:8940
                                                                                         at t.invokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:14051)
                                                                                         at Object.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:3:22982)
                                                                                         at t.invokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:13987)
                                                                                         at e.runTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:11411)
                                                                                         at i (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:8028)
                                                                                         at u (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:2:16275)
                                                                                         at file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:2:16399
                                                                                             at MutationObserver.r (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:2:14841)
```

**Additional findings/notes:**

If i write `console.log(resultSet);`
The return will be `[object object]`
For now it's all in the same class and on the longrun it will be in it's own StorageProvider/Service but i've moved it all here to debug it. (without success so far)

Does someone have a clue what causes the error?

Thanks in advance.

Poerkie

**UPDATE 20-12 (after implementing tips and suggestions):**

current code:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {SQLite} from 'ionic-native';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';


@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
public database: SQLite;
public users;

constructor(private platform: Platform) {
    console.log(' StorageService Initialised');
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.database = new SQLite();
        this.database.openDatabase({name: "data.db", location: "default"}).then(() => {
            console.log("SUCCES Opening DB storageService");
            let s1 = this.createUserTable()
            let s2 = this.database.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS melding (idmelding INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, meldingType TEXT, meldingTitel TEXT, meldingOmschrijving TEXT, ruimte INTEGER, user_iduser INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (user_iduser) REFERENCES user(iduser)); ", {});

            return Promise.all([s1, s2]).then(() => {
                console.log('creating database complete!');
                let i1 = this.insertUser();
                let i2 = this.database.executeSql("INSERT INTO user (firstname, lastname, castletype, castleHealth) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", ['Klaas', 'Janssen', 'mannelijk', '5']);

                return Promise.all([i1, i2]).then((res) => {
                    console.log('all insert querys executed', res);
                }).then(() => {
                    console.log('executing sql statement');
                    return this.database.executeSql('SELECT * FROM user', []);

                }).then((resultSet) => {
                    console.log('after then((resultset): ' + resultSet);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(resultSet, undefined, 2));
                    if (resultSet.res.rows.length > 0) {
                        console.log('if statement true');
                        this.users = [];
                        for (let i = 0; i < resultSet.res.rows.length; i++) {
                            console.log('forloop');
                            this.users.push({
                                "iduser": resultSet.res.rows.item(i).iduser,
                                "firstname": resultSet.res.rows.item(i).firstname,
                                "lastname": resultSet.res.rows.item(i).lastname,
                            });
                        }
                        console.log('after forloop');
                    }
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error("db error", error);
                })
            })
        }, (error) => {
            console.log("ERROR oepening DB storageService: ", error);
        });
    });
}

public createUserTable() {
    this.database.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (iduser INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT, castleType TEXT, castleHealth INTEGER); ", {}).then((data) => {
        console.log("USER TABLE CREATED: ", data);
    }, (error) => {
        console.error("USER Unable to execute sql", error);
    });
}

public insertUser() {
        this.database.executeSql("INSERT INTO user (firstname, lastname, castletype, castleHealth) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", ['Jan', 'Klaassen', 'mannelijk', '10']).then((data) => {
            console.log('Insert Succesful');
        }, (error) => {
            console.error('user not inserted: ' + error);
        });
    }
}
```

**nexus 5 outputlog:**

```
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 6 :  StorageService Initialised
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] " StorageService Initialised", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (6)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 6 : CastleService initialized
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "CastleService initialized", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (6)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 5 : SlimLabsService initialized
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "SlimLabsService initialized", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (5)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 5 : Logging in!
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "Logging in!", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (5)
12-20 07:48:04.042 796-18483/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@fd827af attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@7d616de
D/CordovaWebViewImpl: onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 19 : DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(19)] "DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (19)
I/App: WARNING: Back Button Default Behavior will be overridden.  The backbutton event will be fired!
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js: Line 175 : OPEN database: data.db
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(175)] "OPEN database: data.db", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js (175)
V/SQLitePlugin: Android db implementation: built-in android.database.sqlite package
V/info: Open sqlite db: /data/user/0/com.ionicframework.cwistlev1105374/databases/data.db
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js: Line 179 : OPEN database: data.db - OK
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(179)] "OPEN database: data.db - OK", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js (179)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 6 : SUCCES Opening DB storageService
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "SUCCES Opening DB storageService", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (6)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 6 : USER TABLE CREATED: 
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "USER TABLE CREATED: ", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (6)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 6 : creating database complete!
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "creating database complete!", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (6)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 6 : Insert Succesful
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "Insert Succesful", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (6)
12-20 07:48:04.629 1596-1596/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onFinishInput()
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 6 : all insert querys executed
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "all insert querys executed", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (6)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 6 : executing sql statement
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "executing sql statement", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (6)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 6 : after then((resultset): [object Object]
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "after then((resultset): [object Object]", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (6)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 6 : {
                                                                                             "rows": {
                                                                                               "length": 42
                                                                                             },
                                                                                             "rowsAffected": 0
                                                                                           }
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "{
                                                                                "rows": {
                                                                                  "length": 42
                                                                                },
                                                                                "rowsAffected": 0
                                                                              }", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (6)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 6 : db error
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "db error", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (6)
```

**additional information:** 
There isn't more information about the error or I don't know how to retrieve that. (not getting a stack trace or anything);
Why doesn't it want to pass on the results! into the users[]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Suraj Rao about the async result. I would add that you could do all the create tables in a Promise.all(). And when in between 'then' statement, place a 'return' on the query which result is expected in the next "then". Eg:

```
    query.then( (res) => { return query2 } 
).then( (res2) => { do something }
).catch( (err) => {...});
```

In your case:

```
let db = new SQLite();
console.log("open database app.compontent")
db.openDatabase({
  name: "data.db",
  location: "default"
}).then(() => {
  let s1 = db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (iduser INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT, castleType TEXT, castleHealth INTEGER); ", {});
  let s2 = db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS melding (idmelding INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, meldingType TEXT, meldingTitel TEXT, meldingOmschrijving TEXT, ruimte INTEGER, user_iduser INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (user_iduser) REFERENCES user(iduser)); ", {})
  let sN = db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE ....); 

   return Promise.all([s1,s2,....,sN]);
).then(
   () => {
      console.log('Creating database complete!');
      let i1 =   db.executeSql("INSERT INTO user (firstname, lastname, castletype, castleHealth) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", ['Jan', 'Klaassen', 'mannelijk', '10']);
      let i2 =   db.executeSql("INSERT INTO user (firstname, lastname, castletype, castleHealth) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", ['Klaas', 'Janssen', 'mannelijk', '5']);
      let iN = db.executeSql("INSERT INTO ....");

      return Promise.all([i1,i2,....,iN]);

).then(
   (res) => {
       console.log('all insert over ' , res)
    }
).then(
   () => {return  db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM user', []);}
).then(
  (resultSet) => {
        if(resultSet.res.rows.length > 0) {
          this.users = [];
          for(let i = 0; i < resultSet.res.rows.length; i++) {
            this.users.push({
               "iduser": resultSet.res.rows.item(i).iduser,
               "firstname": resultSet.res.rows.item(i).firstname,
                "lastname": resultSet.res.rows.item(i).lastname,
            });
          }
        }
   }
).catch(
   (error) => {
       console.error("db error", error);
   }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help in the first place. I'm trying to implement the Promise.all([function1, function2, ect]), However the function are still triggered after the then clausule from the Promise.all(); Could you adjust your Example a bit more, i have trouble inplementing it.

Comment: @nyluje Thanks for providing such an extensive example code.
It works perfect (created the database then inserts it ect) However it still gets an error (and goes "into" the catch)

Comment: what error?  if you run it several times you might want to replace "INSERT INTO" statement by "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO"

Comment: @nyluje I've updated it with all the information i've got myself.

Comment: i think you should just go with `resultSet.rows.length` and `resultSet.rows.item(i)['whatever attribute from db']`, I don't get why you put a 'res' in between.

Comment: I d also suggest you to have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653493/ionic2-sqliteplugin-is-not-defined/40656960#40656960, So you could use WebSQL in a chrome browser on your desktop for your test. Chrome console gives more logs about objects, make it easier to debug.

Answer (score 2):

The db related functions you are using return a promise.
The then() is asynchronous meaning all your db functions from create,insert,select may execute before one or more of the then method is called.

Suppose you have only user table,You will need to

```
db.executeSql(`
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
        iduser INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
        firstname TEXT, 
        lastname TEXT, 
        castleType TEXT, 
        castleHealth INTEGER
    ); `, {})
    .then((data) => {
        console.log("USER TABLE CREATED: ", data);
        db.executeSql(`
        INSERT INTO user (
            firstname, 
            lastname, 
            castletype, 
            castleHealth
        ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)`, 
        ['Jan', 'Klaassen', 'mannelijk', '10'])
        .then((data) => {
            //select here
            console.log("Inserted row 1: ", data);
        }, (error) => {
            console.error("Unable to insert row 1: ", error);
        });
    }, (error) => {
        console.error("USER Unable to execute sql", error);
    });
```

and so on.
Your resultset.res is probably null because your table is not created yet.
Also to print objects  do : `console.log(JSON.stringify(resultSet,undefined,2));`

Comment: Thanks for the console.log(JSON.strinify(resultSet,undefined,2));
It does give a return value so I can work with that partially, not a lot of luck with fixing the actual issue though

Answer (score 2):

Hope it will work for you, refer the below simple implementation.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html',
  providers:[SQLite]
})
export class AboutPage {
 
  rows: any;
  data: any;
  public people: Array<Object>;
  getdata: string;
   
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private sqlite: SQLite) {

  this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'data.db',
  location: 'default'
}).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS supriya(name VARCHAR(32))', {})
      .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));

   db.executeSql('INSERT INTO supriya VALUES (?)', ['Supriya']).then(() => console.log('value inserted in SQL'))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  
  db.executeSql('select * from supriya', []).then(data => {
          console.log("select statment executed"+ data);
    
             this.people = [];

       if(data.rows.length > 0) {
                for(var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
    
    this.people.push({name: data.rows.item(i).name});
    console.log(data.rows.item(i).name);
                }
            }
        }, (error) => {
            console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error));
             
    
              
   })
   })
}
}
```

```html
<ion-list>
         <ion-item *ngFor="let person of people">
             {{person.name}}
         </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
```

Comment: It helps me a lot.Thanks